# Multiple messages in screen PyQt5

Tags: python, qt

Here is my code

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
loginWindow = loadUi('~/mainwindow.ui')
okconnect = loadUi('~/okconnect.ui')



def prueba2(test):
    print(test + " Testing2")



def prueba(test):
    print (test)

    okconnect.show()
    okconnect.getvmsButton.clicked.connect(lambda: prueba2(test))



loginWindow.show()

loginWindow.connectButton.clicked.connect(lambda: prueba("test"))

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I press "connect" button, a new window is opened, with a button, "getvmsButton", when I press this button, its show in console the print line in def prueba2(test), but if I close the window, and then I click again in connect button, the window open again and "getvmsButton" is pressed again, the console show 2 messages instead of 1. If I repeat the process, more messages are showed.

What should I change to show only one messages when I close and open several times the window?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

When you close your GUI by 'x' doesn't mean you disconnected the button click signal, therefore, every time you click the 'connect' button, the loginWindow will create a new button.clicked event and keep the old ones. A quick solution to this is to define a close-event for the 'x' clicks. Here provided is just a way to close the old signal events.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


OKConnect(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.okconnect = loadUi('~/okconnect.ui')
        self.okconnect.closeEvent = self.closeEvent

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("testing2 closing")
        # to close the old getvmsButton signals
        self.okconnect.getvmsButton.disconnect()


# Here below is exactly your code

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
loginWindow = loadUi('~/mainwindow.ui')
okconnect = OKConnect()

def prueba2(test):
    print(test + " Testing2")

def prueba(test):
    print (test)

    okconnect.show()
    okconnect.getvmsButton.clicked.connect(lambda: prueba2(test))


loginWindow.show()

loginWindow.connectButton.clicked.connect(lambda: prueba("test"))

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am not sure about your .ui files, the code may not work on yours.